# How to access HTTP Cookie in Node.JS - JWT

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, jwt

This might seem like a redundant question, but please hear me out first:

I'm working with a React Frontend and a Node Backend. I'm using JWT to deal with user authentication. Right now, I'm having trouble actually working with the JWT and performing the authentication. Here's where I'm stuck:

~ I try setting the token as an http cookie in my backend. If i work with postman, I see the token being set. However, when I use req.cookies.token to try and receive the token cookie to perform validation in the backend, I get an undefined value. Am I supposed to be sending the cookie from the frontend to the backend somehow? I feel like this is the part that I am missing.

Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

SO I can give you an alternative solution to handling session making use of **express-session** and **connect-mongodb-session** this has tend to been the popular and somewhat secure solution for server session handling

**Firstly you will need the following packages**

`npm i express-session connect-mongodb-session` or yarn add express-session connect-mongodb-session

**Now that we have packages that we need to setup our mongoStore and express-session middleware:**

```
//Code in server.js/index.js (Depending on your server entry point)
import expressSession from "express-session";
import MongoDBStore from "connect-mongodb-session";
import cors from "cors";
const mongoStore = MongoDBStore(expressSession);

const store = new mongoStore({
  collection: "userSessions",
  uri: process.env.mongoURI,
  expires: 1000,
});
app.use(
  expressSession({
    name: "SESS_NAME",
    secret: "SESS_SECRET",
    store: store,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
      sameSite: false,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
      maxAge: 1000,
      httpOnly: true,
    },
  })
);
```

**Now the session middleware is ready but now you have to setup cors to accept your ReactApp so to pass down the cookie and have it set in there by server**

```
//Still you index.js/server.js (Server entry point)

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["POST", "PUT", "GET", "OPTIONS", "HEAD"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);
```

**Now our middlewares are all setup now lets look at your login route**

```
router.post('/api/login', (req, res)=>{
    //Do all your logic and now below is how you would send down the cooki

    //Note that "user" is the retrieved user when you were validating in logic
    // So now you want to add user info to cookie so to validate in future
    const sessionUser = {
       id: user._id,
       username: user.username,
       email: user.email,
    };
    //Saving the info req session and this will automatically save in your     mongoDB as configured up in sever.js(Server entry point)
    request.session.user = sessionUser;

    //Now we send down the session cookie to client
    response.send(request.session.sessionID);

})
```

**Now our server is ready but now we have to fix how we make request in client so that this flow can work 100%:**

**Code below: React App where you handling logging in**

```
//So you will have all your form logic and validation and below
//You will have a function that will send request to server 

const login = () => {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("username", username);
    data.append("password", password);

    axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/user-login", data, {
      withCredentials: true, // Now this is was the missing piece in the client side 
    });
};
```

**Now with all this you have now server sessions cookies as httpOnly**