# How do I delete a HttpOnly Cookie on the client?

Tags: java, reactjs, cookies, jax-rs, cookie-httponly

I have a website that, when a user logs in, creates an Access token which is stored in memory and a Refresh token that is stored in an HttpOnly cookie. When a user logs out I want to delete the HttpOnly cookie. however, since it's HttpOnly I am not able to do this with JavaScript, so instead my plan is to send another cookie from the server that is expired and overwrite the valid cookie. Unfortunately, for some reason, this does not work.

This is how I create the cookie in the first place:

```
 String refreshToken = issueRefreshToken(username);
 long currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
 Date expDate = new Date(currentDate + 60 * 24 * 7 * ONE_MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);

 NewCookie newCookie = new NewCookie("RefreshCookie",
                    refreshToken,
                    "/",
                    null,
                    NewCookie.DEFAULT_VERSION,
                    "Comment",
                    60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
                    expDate,
                    false,
                    true);

            // Return the token  on the response
 return Response.ok(accessToken).cookie(newCookie).header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true).build();
```

This works as intended and creates a Refresh cookie that is valid for one week.

I have another endpoint (/logout) that creates another cookie, which is suppose to overwrite the first one.

```
 @POST
 public Response logout(){
        NewCookie logoutCookie = new NewCookie(
                "RefreshCookie",
                null,
                "/",
                null,
                NewCookie.DEFAULT_VERSION,
                "",
                0,
                new Date(),
                false,
                true);
        return Response.ok().cookie(logoutCookie).header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true).build();
    }
```

This cookie does not even get saved to the frontend when the first client is not set. I have tried to send it from a subpath of where the first cookie is set, with no luck. Is there something that I'm missing here? Is this the wrong way to do it?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem! Logging in and setting a HttpOnly cookie works just fine, but removing that cookie when logging out is impossible? Can't set it to an empty value, changing the max-age to 0 doesn't help either. Have you managed to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

From what you are saying is your are using httpOnly cookie so you have to understand one thing is that from the client-side you wont achieve that because then that then would defeat the purpose of having an httpOnly cookie than that would have just been the same as having a regular cookie.

- So now your solution to get rid of the cookie when a user logs out is on your back-end where I am to believe the cookie was made is where you want want to delete that specific cookie.

Comment: Exactly! However, as far as I can understand, the only way to achieve this is to overwrite the first cookie with a new one that will expire immediately. The problem is that this does not work for me, since the cookie is not saved or overwritten, and I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: You can read through the example I once gave on someone requiring server-side session https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64683813/how-to-access-http-cookie-in-node-js-jwt/64684397#64684397 the sessions are all saved in mongoStore so you can easy handle things like that and that's how I handle express-sessions

Comment: @NtshemboHlongwane If we are to overwrite HttpOnly cookie on the server, what would be a workaround if the server is not currently available (e.g. due to a network issue on the client) but the user intention was to logout?

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie):

> Max-Age=<number>
>
> Indicates the number of seconds until the cookie expires. A zero or negative number will expire the cookie immediately. If both Expires and Max-Age are set, Max-Age has precedence.

Make sure that other attributes (i.e. `Path`) are set correctly: if the client's cookie is set with `Path=/`, the server should set that same value before sending the cookie. Same goes for the other attributes.

This is how I have done it, in Go:

```go
// Taken from the handler that logs users in:
session_id := generateRandomString()
cookie := &http.Cookie{
    Name:     "session",
    Value:    session_id,
    MaxAge:   int(time.Hour.Seconds()),
    Secure:   r.TLS != nil, // r is the typical *http.Request
    HttpOnly: true,
    SameSite: http.SameSiteStrictMode,
    Path:     "/",
}
http.SetCookie(w, cookie)
```

```go
// Taken from the handler that logs users out:
cookie, err := r.Cookie("session")
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, "cookie not found", http.StatusUnauthorized)
    return
}
// Here goes the logic to log out the user.
// Once that is done, it is time to send an expired cookie back:
newCookie := &http.Cookie{
    Name:     "session",
    Value:    cookie.Value,
    MaxAge:   -1,
    Secure:   r.TLS != nil,
    HttpOnly: true,
    SameSite: http.SameSiteStrictMode,
    Path:     "/",
}
http.SetCookie(w, newCookie)
```

From Go's source code for type `Cookie`:

```go
// MaxAge=0 means no 'Max-Age' attribute specified.
// MaxAge<0 means delete cookie now, equivalently 'Max-Age: 0'
```